# AAPT: error: attribute cardcornerRadius not found Error

Tags: android, android-layout, cardview

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardcornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardelevation="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >
```

Every time I try to run my code, it gives me an error telling me that Android Linking failed. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I have added `implementation "com.android.support:design:$android_support_version"`

This library and it`s working, in my case $android_support_version = 28.0.0-alpha3